# enable agent XPs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am trying to run the following script on **SQL 2000:**

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'ave enabled' 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

and get an Error:

"the configuration option 'agent XPs' does not exist or it may be an advanced option"

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Agent XPs` server option only exists on SQL Server 2005+ to enable legacy mail features.

For SQL Server 2000, [it doesn't exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196706%28SQL.80%29.aspx) because you *have* to use Agent XPs for mail. There is no SMTP support via [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx)

I really would considering upgrading, given SQL Server 2012 is due in a few weeks. There is no direct upgrade path from '2000 to '2012.